# Authorization flow for Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Very new to the Microsoft ecosystem, trying to understand the flow.

**Use-case:** we need a Teams bot that sends personal messages to users saying "A customer is waiting at location X" with 2 buttons [Accept] and [Reject] containing personalized links like "https://someurl.com/accept?message=123&user=[user_id]".

**How I think I should do it:**

1. Add a special user "servicenotifications@ourdomain.onmicrosoft.com"
2. Authorize the user & then get a token
3. Use the token in [Send message with cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-send-message-containing-cards) with cards containing button links

**My problem:**  Got confused with [authorizing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) my special user. Examples on auth V2 require to "redirect the user to the Microsoft identity platform /authorize endpoint." — in a nutshell, show them the login screen, ask for consent and so on.

But my user is a special notification bot, there is no human and I need that fully automated without any user interaction at any point. It's basically a background service sending messages under specific circumstances. Like a Slack bot telling you "Hey, reminder, John has birthday tomorrow".

**My questions**:

1. In general, am I moving in the right direction? Or is there a better way for the usecase?
2. How do I authorize this user without showing any login screen? Because that's an app, a bot, it's not a human and will be controlled fully externally.

Comment: You could use the ROPC flow if storing the password is ok for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc. Otherwise you could do the redirect-authenticate once, get a refresh token from that and then use that in the background to get tokens. The second method does mean you don't need to store the password but it's a bit more fragile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since authentication will be initiated by a bot, the ideal solution is to implement the [OAuth2 Client Credentials Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) so that a service principal can be authenticated and authorized. Take a look at [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) for more information.

There may be some operations that may not be allowed for service principals (documented as applications) like [Sending chat message to a chat.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions-for-chat)